# Is there a Xlib DLL for Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, .net-core, x11, xlib

Out of private / experimental interest, I've been writing low-level cross-platform UI functionality with .NET Standard 2.0, and implemented creating a window

- on Windows (via WinAPI P/Invoke) and
- on Linux with an X11 server (via Xlib/libX11 P/Invoke).

So far I can run the X11 code nicely on Linux with MonoDevelop, but I thought it would be useful to develop for an X server running on Windows (like **Cygwin/X** or **Xming X Server**).

For that however, I require an Xlib *Windows DLL* which I can P/Invoke to, as .NET Core only supports Windows DLLs on Windows platforms (AFAIK).

Before I get myself into the trouble of "porting" the Xlib source to compile with MSVC++, I wonder if there is any project available which already creates an Xlib Windows DLL, or if any such compiled DLL is readily available somewhere?

Comment: you can probably just compile xlib under windows. From os it only need networking

Comment: Porting XLib to a difficult platform like Windows is not a weekend project. Cygwin comes with an Xlib implementation, try to use it.

Comment: What exactly do I have to look for in Cygwin? I couldn't find any MSVC headers or a compiled dynamic link library I could use to create the DLL I require.

Comment: There is no such thing as "MSVC headers". There are C headers. You get them by installing the "development" package of X11 llibraries (libx11-devel and friends). They should be under `/usr/include/X11`. The DLLs are under `/lib` IIRC. I'm not sure there are any import libraries; probably not. `gcc` can work without import libraries. For MSVC you will have to create an import library from the dll, there are methods described in a couple of places on the internet.

Comment: I just mentiond MSVC since the last time I tried to build something with the original Xlib, I had several compiler related issues, but I'll look at those headers shipped with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a X11.dll as part of some commercial X server from the mid-1990s for Windows NT, except I don't remember which X server product however. I do know, however, that it'll do what you want.

It's 32-bit, but you can use this DLL: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/segin-utils/X11.dll

I used it to produce a 32-bit Windows build of a window manager I had worked on years ago: https://github.com/segin/matwm2

Build: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/segin-utils/matwm2.exe

If I can figure out how to upload release artifacts to GitHub, I'll probably archive these files there.